# Read data from proc/sys/kernel/

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I want create program for get info about operating system. I tried used syscalls, but think that read from systems files will be more faster (directly). So, i write simple program for read data from file from directory "/proc/sys/kernel/" and want read files: osrelease hostname, ostype and other.... So, i did supposed is just but isn't. When i read file "hostname" i got this:

```
����
```

If i read as superuser i got normal data

```
oleg
```

This is code of my program:

```
global _start

section .data
file db "/proc/sys/kernel/hostname",0

section .bss
buf resb 1024
descriptor resb 4
len equ 1024


section .text
_start:

    mov eax, 5
    mov ebx, file
    mov ecx, 2
    int 80h
    mov [descriptor], eax

read:
    mov eax, 3  ;read text
    mov ebx, [descriptor];  
    mov ecx, buf    ;read to variable buf
    mov edx, len    ;size of bug
    int 80h     ;interrupt

print_text:
    mov edx, eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, buf
    int 80h

close_file:
    mov eax, 6
    mov ebx, [descriptor]
    int 80h

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

So, i thought change name of file and can get other system information, but it's mistake, because i don't got result. So, i change path to file, compile project and execute program as super user and i don't get result. Nothing...
I can read all files except this directory ("proc/sys/kernel").
I googled information about this problem and don't find similar problem. I think it is security of OS, but i only read info, don't write... I understand that using syscall more simple, but want undestand structure of OS. Why i can't read info from this directory? So, can you attach useful info about this problam, please?

Comment: Tip: you can see what went wrong if you run your binary under `strace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mov ecx, 2
```

A `flags` value of 2 for `open()` is `O_RDWR`.  You're attempting to open the file read-write, which as a normal user you cannot do because it's writable only by `root` (mode `0644` on my system).  Unix permission checks are done when you open the file, not on each individual read and write, so this fails even though you do not intend to actually write to the file.

So the `open` call returns a negative error code (which you don't check for), you pass this as the fd to read which thus also fails with a negative error code (which you also don't check for) and thus your buffer still contains a bunch of zeros.  You pass this negative error code as the length to `write()`, which interprets it as a huge positive number and writes out not only the zero bytes from `buf`, but also whatever garbage follows it in memory, until it runs off the end of your address space.

This does work for me as root.  I don't quite understand your last paragraph and can't tell whether it does or doesn't work for you in that case.  If it doesn't, you may have securelevels or some other mechanism that prevents writing the file even as root.  Note that some other files in `/proc/sys/kernel` are not writable even by `root`, e.g. `/proc/sys/kernel/version` which is `0444`, so for those files your program will fail as above even if you are `root`.

But since you don't care about writing the file, just use flags `O_RDONLY` which has the value 0.  So `xor ecx, ecx` instead.  With this change the program works for me as a normal user.

Error checking throughout would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. It's really working. I thought that i only read, but at program set mode as read-write and i can't read info. So, thank you :)
Sorry for my language. The language barrier...